# Pandas - Converting CSV to JSON - organize with groupby and then remove index key

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that I'm trying to convert to JSON with Pandas. It has multiple headers but for the sake of simplicity let's just say it has 3: "region", "state", and "salesperson". Three columns, three rows that often have repeating values within (state names and such).

My ideal result is:

```
{
    "salesperson": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "values": [
                {
                    "region": "North America",
                    "state": "Connecticut"
                },
                {
                    "region": "North America",
                    "state": "Vermont"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "values": [
                {
                    "region": "North America",
                    "state": "New York"
                },
                {
                    "region": "North America",
                    "state": "New Hampshire"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I currently have for reading the data and turning it into JSON.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('Foo.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1",
                    escapechar='\\')
result = (df.groupby(['salesperson'])
            .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
            .to_json(orient='table')
            )
return result
```

`.to_json(orient='table')` is close, it gives me

```
"data": [
    {
        "salesperson": "John Doe",
        "values": [
            {
                "region": "North America",
                "state": "Connecticut",
                "salesperson": "John Doe"
            },
```

However "salesperson" is still in the "values". I've tried

```py
result = (df.groupby(['salesperson'])
            .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
            .drop('salesperson')
            .to_json(orient='table')
            )
```

But that doesn't seem to be the correct way.

I'm not sure how to tell it to use "salesperson" as the index & remove it from the output, without actually editing the JSON file after it's created.

Comment: can you share a sample of your csv file please

Comment: have you tried index=False?

Answer (score 0):

The code below deletes the key not needed.

**Step-1:**

Assign a variable.

```
data = {
        "salesperson": "John Doe",
        "values": [
            {
                "region": "North America",
                "state": "Connecticut",
                "salesperson": "John Doe"
            }]
       }
```

**Step-2:** 
Delete key

```
del data['salesperson']
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to apply `drop` to the key before applying `to_dict()`

```py
result = df.groupby(df.salesperson).apply(
    lambda x: x.drop('salesperson', 1).to_dict('records')).to_json(orient='index')
```

This removed the key from the resulting JSON values while preserving it as the index.